# move file from ftp to local using apachecamel

Tags: java, ftp, apache-camel

I am new to Apachecamel
I have a requirement to move a file from ftp location to my local folder:

I am using below route to do this:

```
import java.io.File;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;

public class CopyFtp {
    public static void main(final String[] arguments) {
        final CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
        /*
         * ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new
         * ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin", "admin",
         * ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
         * camelContext.addComponent("test-jms",
         * JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
         */
        try {
            camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() throws Exception {

                    from("ftp://user@server.com/folder?password=abc&delay=10000").routeId("testRoute")
                            .process(new Processor() {

                                @Override
                                public void process(Exchange msg) throws Exception {
                                    File file = msg.getIn().getBody(File.class);
                                    String file1 = msg.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                                    System.out.println("" + file + file1);
                                }

                            }).to("file://E:/TestingWatch1/output");

                }
            });
            camelContext.start();
            // Thread.sleep(10*60*1000);
            // camelContext.stop();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't see file is moving from FTP location to my local folder,
am I missing something here?

Comment: Exiting how?  Do you mean your file that you are trying to move doesn't move at all?  I think you are falling into the trap everyone does when they first start using Camel, take a look at this: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Comment: File is not moving it to my local directory.

Comment: I'm fairly sure what is happening (i'm guessing since I'm looking at your code) is that Camel isn't continually running, so the route isn't running, so your file isn't getting transferred.  Have you had a chance to look at that link?  You need to call `main.run()` basically in order to keep Camel running

Answer (score 0):

In your case program is finished before context event fully started as there are no blocking there. Here you can see how to run it properly and leave running: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html